# Auto delete WordPress comments

Tags: comments

Is there a way to delete pending WordPress comments after X days?

I looked into

```
do_action( 'wp_set_comment_status', $comment->comment_ID, 'delete' );
```

but now sure how to take it from here.

Comment: No, that would call the status change hook but not actually change the status - it's something WordPress does after changing the status to notify any interested code. Is it just deleting the comments you need help with, you've already got the scheduled jobs to find and delete old comments set up?

Comment: No I didn't. I need the whole code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a schedule event.

It is a best practice to assign this schedule event to the activation of the plugin, and it should be cleared when the plugin is deactivated.

```php
/**
 * Plugin activation
 * - create schedule event
 */
function enlsbv7_activation() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'enlsbv7_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'enlsbv7_event' );
    }
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'enlsbv7_activation' );

/**
 * Plugin deactivation
 * - clear schedule event
 */
function enlsbv7_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'enlsbv7_event' );
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'enlsbv7_deactivation' );

/**
 * Delete old pending comments
 */
function enlsbv7_event_delete_old_pending_comments() {

    $args = array(
        'date_query'     => array(
            'before' => '3 days ago',
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'status'         => 'hold',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
    );

    $comment_ids = get_comments( $args );

    if ( ! empty( $comment_ids ) ) {
        foreach ( $comment_ids as $comment_id ) {
            wp_delete_comment( $comment_id, true );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'enlsbv7_event', 'enlsbv7_event_delete_old_pending_comments' );
```

This will delete all pending comments older than 3 days. The schedule event runs daily.